# Compilation error with Lombok dependency on SpringBoot Application - Maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, compilation, lombok

I want my application to use the Lombok dependency, mainly because of the ***@Getters, @Setters, @NoArgsConstructor and @AllArgsConstructors***, I already have the plugin installed in IntelliJ and the Annotation Processors configuration enabled. When compiling the project Maven throws error: *'cannot find symbol'*, everywhere ***getters*** and ***setters*** are being used.
This is the dependency that i'm using:

```
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The version of SpringBoot I am using is *3.0.2*

[image]

Comment: Please check again. Maybe restart IntelliJ.  With Lombok plugin installed and enabled and with Annotation processing enabled this works for me.

Answer (score 1):

- Firstly remove the scope tag from the pom
- run the "mvn clean compile"
- make sure the lombok dependency has been imported into your project and you must see it under the external dependencies in your project explorer
- then use the @Data annotation it makes your code less busy